# Remote Server Unavilable in Business Central

Tags: jbpm, kie-server

I am using docker compose image to connect jbpm with postgresql.
I have done the authentication of business central through database users by changing login module in security domain section.
After successful login of database user, using url http://localhost:8080/business-central/kie-wb.jsp , i am deploying project to execution server , but remote server is not available there .
See below image :

[Remote Server Unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfwxQ.png)

When i check for logs it shows some warnings and errors as below : 
Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism

[Warnings Regarding controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Illn.png)

Additionally it shows error like, Error while creating container for Project.Cannot find Kie Module.

What is causing the remote server not available here ? Which step i missed could anyone please tell.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are configuring user using DatabaseServerLoginModule, you will have to configure "kie-server" user and password in standalone.xml.

Try adding below properties in standalone.xml and map with the required user.

```
<property name="org.kie.server.user" value="newUser"/> 
<property name="org.kie.server.pwd" value="passwd"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.controller.user" value="newUser"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.controller.pwd" value="passwd"/>
```

Also, remove key-store related properties if it's added.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt reply.I tried this settings but it doesn't work,also i tried adding org.kie.server.controller.user ,pwd too. but it doesn't work.Is it realted to authentication ? do we need to add hasing technique or encoding to store password ? or anything else ?

Comment: I was able to sync with kie-server after adding "org.kie.server.user", "org.kie.server.controller.user" & paswds properties. Does the user added as "kie-server" role?

Comment: Also, just test by removing "kie.keystore" related properties once.

Comment: Thanks Again @Sudhish Nair , it works for me ,1) by adding kie.user/passwd and controller user and passwd .2)by removing kie.keysotre related properties.
Just last question, how do we store encrypted password in database ? I tried 
<module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value ="MD5"/>
<module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
<module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="nobody"/>
<module-option name="hashUserPassword" value="true"/>
<module-option name="hashCharset" value="true"/>
<module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="true"/> , but doesn't work for me.Could you tell

Comment: Hi Neha, I have not tried password hashing much so not sure about it. Maybe this article would be helpful [Link](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/how-to-encrypt-wildfly-datasource-password)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I can't figure out the exact solution?

Comment: Hi Walid, Did you remove  "kie.keystore" properties as suggested in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

Installing the Business Central on WildFly requires to install all the KieServer components available in the KIE Execution Server Distribution.zip (hhtp://www.drools.org) plus the set of System Properties already said in the accepted answer. You also need an application user and to increase the JVM settings of WildFly, to allow starting WildFly with the above applications.

This tutorial cover in details the above steps: [Installing the Business Central on WildFly](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/jbpm6/installing-the-business-central-on-wildfly)